# Dummy variable that is a sub-category of another dummy variable

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I'm wondering if there are any statistical issues with using a dummy variable that is a subcategory of another dummy variable.

For example:

Let's say I am trying to predict a binary outcome of whether a child goes to college.

If I have one dummy variable "NYC" for "lives in New York City" and another "Bronx" for "lives in the Bronx" (which is part of NYC) then "NYC" will always be 1 when "Bronx" is 1 but not vice versa.

As I understand it this shouldn't create a "dummy variable trap" but is this a problem in some other way?

Comment: I think doing this might introduce some undesirable dependence between your independent variables since, as you said,
`then "NYC" will always be 1 when "Bronx" is 1`. 
What about trying something like splitting your `NYC` variable into two distinct factors - `NYC-Not Bronx` and `NYC-Bronx`?

Comment: You may do as you did. You'll test main effects `nyc vs not nyc` and `bronx vs not bronx`. Or you may do as nrussel adviced: this is the same as nesting factor `bronx` in factor `nyc`, and you'll be testing effects `(nyc & bronx) vs both no` and `(nyc & not bronx) vs both no`

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is sort of what I was wondering... Would the "Bronx" variable account for the fact that it starts initially as a "NYC" variable and then adjust correctly according to that without having to code as "NYC-Not Bronx"?  So sort of "undo" the fact that it is also always coded as "NYC".

Comment: Yeah, you just specify `bronx` factor as nested in `nyc` factor. That means that your "regression" package must be like ANOVA package - able to take factor predictors.